# How metamask popup opens whenever something has to do with metamask provider?

Tags: ether, metamask, ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm trying to build the similar wallet like metamask, I couldn't figure out how metamask popup opens whenever the code has to do something with metamask provider.
Are they using any logic behind that?